# Multiline input in console

Tags: go, input, terminal

Been looking a bit everywhere for this, but nothing quite answers it.

I can create a multiline prompt input in the console with Go by having a scan or bufio.readstring loop, and check for an end-of-input character to end input. Or I can even pass whatever character to bufio.readstring so that I can keep reading after \n has been entered.

But in both cases, user can not backspace its way to a precedent line, because the previous line have been entered and validated.

How would it work, to let user backspace to the previous line, or move cursor freely between lines of a console input ?

I can imagine something with clearing terminal and redrawing. Is that the only way ?

Comment: Downvote might be more useful if explained with a comment ....

Comment: To do that you need to do your own terminal management. If you just read stdin, you will not be able to go back, once the line is read, it is read. You need something like a readline or curses library, so you can read the input one character at a time and deal with backspaces and enters and what not on your own

Answer (score 2):

You could use a readline library, as this demo shows

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/chzyer/readline"
)

func main() {
    rl, err := readline.NewEx(&readline.Config{
        Prompt:                 "> ",
        HistoryFile:            "/tmp/readline-multiline",
        DisableAutoSaveHistory: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rl.Close()

    for {
        cmd, err := rl.Readline()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        rl.SaveHistory(cmd)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I have tried on before. This is good enough for some mutliline input, but do not let you edit the previous line (just "recall it" from history on the new line. Mad Wombat's comment's is right and I should use a complete cui librairy.